# Create a list element and colour it using a user's input (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-input

I am trying to create a function that allows users to add an item to a list using an input field and colour that list item based on a dropdown box. 
I have figured out how to create the list item from the user's input, however, I am very stuck in how to colour it based on the user's other input (where they choose the list items colour).

Below is an image of what these inputs look like to the user.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfXQo.png)

Below is the javascript and HTML:

```js
function newElement2() {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
      var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
      li.appendChild(t);
      if (inputValue === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
      }
      document.getElementById("myInput2").value = "";
    
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      span.className = "close";
      span.appendChild(txt);
      li.appendChild(span);

      for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() {
          var div = this.parentElement;
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">]
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="folder-popup">
       <div class="form-popup" id="popupForm2">
        <form class="form-container">
          <h2 class="addfolder">Add A Folder:</h2>
          <label for="foldername">
          <a class="givefoldername">Folder Name:</a>
          </label>
          <div id="myDIV" class="header">
            <input type="text" id="myInput2" class="foldernameinput" placeholder="Folder Name">
            </div>
        <div>
          <label for="colour">
          <a class="colourdrop">Colour:</a>
          </label>
        </div>

       <div class="dropdown">
       <select class="dropdown-content">
       <a>Select A Colour...</a>
       <option>Red</option>
       <option>Orange</option>
       <option>Yellow</option>
       <option>Light Green</option>
       <option>Dark Green</option>
       <option>Mint</option>
       <option>Light Blue</option>
       <option>Dark Blue</option>
       <option>Light Purple</option>
       <option>Dark Purple</option>
       <option>Light Pink</option>
       <option>Pink</option>
       <option>Brown</option>
       <option>White</option>
       <option>Black</option>
       </select>
       </div>
        <div class="addnclose">
          <span onclick="newElement2()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close2" onclick="closeForm2()">Close</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should give the `<select>` element an id, so that you can reference it easily,
2. You can get the selected text with `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text` where `sel` is the select box.
3. You can set the style (i.e. color or background-color) with the style element.

Putting that together looks something like this:

`<select class="dropdown-content" id="sel">`
...

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
var color = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
li.style.color = color;
```